# Панель открытых окон

Tags: java, jsf

Скажите пожалуйста, как на java server face реализовать панель открытых окон?
Строим учетную программу, нужно открыть несколько окон одновременно в одной вкладке браузера, хотим, что бы пользователь мог сворачивать окна и по требованию развернуть свернутое окно.

Comment: вы понимаете, что это не будут настоящие окна? на мой взгляд - это сильно усложнит интерфейс, как сточки зрения пользователя, так и сточки зрения разработчика.

Comment: на счет настоящих окон то скорее всего нет, хотим, что бы в главном окне открывались окна не браузера, а самой формы как бы, вот в голове крутиться как это должно быть но понимаю, что как то бредово звучит на счет реализации

Comment: может видели, есть такая учетная система 1с предприятие, вот там можно внизу (по умолчанию) сворачивать окошки открытых документов, вот что то на подобие этого хочу

Comment: вы видели где-нибудь в вебе реализацию MDI? я не могу припомнить.

Comment: не видел, я если честно только сейчас узнал об этом

Comment: а упомянутая система она разве на вебе? по моему это настольное приложение.

Comment: нет, там не дестктоп по (хотя есть уже реализация на вебе) , интересует, может в вебе на jsf возможно что то хотя бы схожее сделать

Comment: да, только что проверил, в 1с реализации на вебе нет возможности той что я хочу так же

Comment: А что сейчас в тренде в этом направлении?

Comment: на мой взгляд - бек-энд отдельно, фронт-энд отдельно и фронт необходимо писать на js (или что-то, что в него transpile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если использовать `JSF`-фреймворк `Primefaces`, то там есть именно то, что вам нужно. Вот пример страницы с диалогами, которые открываются по нажатии кнопки, а при сворачивании прикрепляются к нижней кромке страницы браузера:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<f:view>
<h:head/>

<h:body>
    <p:commandLink onclick="PF('dialog1').show()">button 1</p:commandLink>
    <br/>
    <p:commandLink onclick="PF('dialog2').show()">button 2</p:commandLink>
    <br/>
    <p:commandLink onclick="PF('dialog3').show()">button 3</p:commandLink>
    <br/>

    <p:dialog header="dialog 1" resizable="true" modal="false"
              draggable="true" widgetVar="dialog1"
              minimizable="true" maximizable="true">
        dialog1
    </p:dialog>
    <p:dialog header="dialog 2" resizable="true" modal="false"
              draggable="true" widgetVar="dialog2"
              minimizable="true" maximizable="true">
        dialog2
    </p:dialog>
    <p:dialog header="dialog 3" resizable="true" modal="false"
              draggable="true" widgetVar="dialog3"
              minimizable="true" maximizable="true">
        dialog3
    </p:dialog>
</h:body>
```

В результате получается такая страница:
[image: Один диалог открыт, остальные свёрнуты]

*dialog 1* открыт, остальные два диалога - свёрнуты.